# How to import an export type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Hi I am new to typescript & i am now trying to import a type

This is the export statement. These are exported from different file

```
export type OutlineItemData = {
     readonly lessonId: string;
     readonly title: string;
     readonly timeEstimate?: string;
     readonly status: OutlineItemStatus;
   };
    export type OutlineStateProps = {
      readonly items: OutlineItemData[];
    };
```

The component which i am trying to import got many other props imported already.

```
import { OutlineItemData, OutlineStateProps } from './OutlineComponent'


export type LessonDrawerStateProps = {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly contentKey: string;
};

export type LessonDrawerDispatchProps = {
  readonly requestDrawerScroll: (request: DrawerScrollRequest) => void;
  readonly onBackClicked: () => void;
};

//importing here
    type LessonDrawerProps = LessonDrawerStateProps & LessonDrawerDispatchProps & RouteComponentProps & OutlineStateProps;

type LessonDrawerState = {
  isDesktop: boolean;
  isTitleAtTop: boolean;
  isUncollapsed: boolean;
};

export class LessonDrawer extends Component<
  LessonDrawerProps,
  LessonDrawerState
> {
  headerRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

  contentRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

  constructor(props: LessonDrawerProps) {
    super(props);
    this.lessonDrawerWrapperRef = React.createRef();
    this.contentElement = null;
    this.contentObserver = new ResizeObserver(() =>
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.setState({
          contentUpdatedCounter: this.state.contentUpdatedCounter + 1,
        });
      })
    );
}
```

As you can see in the script , I am trying to import with `&` to `LessonDrawerProps` but
i am getting the following error

```
Property 'items' is missing in type '{ children: Element; route: RouteComponentProps<{ labId: string; }, StaticContext, any>; }' but required in type 'Pick<ClassAttributes<Component<Pick<LessonDrawerProps, "title"
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: My react is a bit rusty but it could be because where you used the `LessonDrawer` component, you didn't give it the `items` prop.